# Set target framework to 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, prerequisites

I have a small project which needs .net version 4.5 because of Compression. This is my App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup>   
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

But when I try to run the program on a stock Windows 7 system, it says that I need to install v4.0.30319. This way the user have to install v4.0 first, THEN the v4.5. Is there a way to set it so it will need v4.5 by default?

I'm using VS2015 if that changes anything

Comment: Do you have other components/references that would require a lesser .NET version? The reason I am asking: If you remove the supportedRuntime-Tag altogether from your app.config, then the .NET loader will take the <TargetFrameworkVersion> from your project into account. If that is .NET 4.5 then this should be your minimum required .NET version by default anyway.

Comment: It is not clear from your question: are you using a setup to install the prerequisites or not?

Comment: @Dan no, that'd be overkill in this project.

Comment: Different version numbers, 4.030319 is the CLR version.  It is the same for any .NET 4.x install.  [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/03/07/optimizing-the-net-framework-deployment-experience-for-users-and-developers/) describes what is *supposed* to happen, note that the dialog doesn't mention 4.0.30319 anywhere.  So maybe that machine isn't as stock as you hope it is.

Comment: Please create an installer to guide your users. Don't rely on the ugly message Windows provides and leave your users in frustration.

Comment: Yes, Fx 4.5 relies on 4.0. Furthermore, support for 4.5.0 has ended, go to 4.5.2 or 4.6.2 .

Comment: How will the application be distributed? If it's an intranet the sysadmin can ensure all machines have at least .NET 4.5.2 installed. If not, then you need a setup. If this is not an option, then you need an "installation instructions"  document, telling the users what yo do when they see the "v4.0.30319"-specific error message.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, according to the MSDN article on `<supportedRuntime>` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w4atty68(v=vs.110).aspx), your current solution is the correct way to check the version. It seems the .NET 4.0 Update 3 Framework is required as a base for any future versions. But this is an assumption, I'd be happy to be corrected here.

**Update**: I did a litlte research, and .NET 4.5 effectively replaces .NET 4.0 on the system. In accordance to the article I mentioned, it seems that everything from .NET 4.0 and above seems to be identified with a version string of "v4.0.30319" in the metadata of the assemblies, hence the .NET loader will always *think* that version has to be installed first.

BUT since .NET 4.x replaces the old one, I would assume that you can install .NET 4.5+ directly without the need to install .NET 4.0 first.

In short: I assume that you can install .NET 4.5 directly without installing .NET 4.0  first. If the user doesn't have either, the application will *tell*  him to install 4.0, which is not neccessary, but this is what the PE tells the loader. I don't think you can check for .NET 4.5 yourself in one turn without some sort of "bootstrapping". By that I mean writing a small program that checks the registry for the installed version and, if the correct version is installed, launches your actual program.

Comment: So I can't do the version check in one turn?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I assume that is the case. Hopefully someone will correct me on this, because I would find that very cumbersome myself.